# Android - How to get all postal codes in specified radius from location?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, location, google-api, google-places-api

How can I in my Android app get all postal codes in radius of 5 km from specified localisation (giving latitude and longitude)?

Can I use one of Google APIs for this?